# How to define dynamic key in object in array of objects with @Prop() decorator in schema? Mongoose, NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I have array of object like this

```js
const array = [
  {key1: value1},
  {key2: value2},
  ...
]
```

How to define it correctly in schema with @Prop decorator?

```js
@Schema()
export class Entity{

  @Prop()  // Here
  body: ; // and here

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

// Any key as string, and value as a number.
export interface CustomData {
  [key: string]: number;
}

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop({ type: [Object] })
  customData: CustomData[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```